# Add or Edit if already exists

Tags: django

I'm working on a web application that has a number of forms that allow the user to submit data to the database.

The data is linked to a project, and from the project page, I have a drop-down list that allows you to select what information you want to add to the project.

At the moment I have two views linked to two dropdown lists. One to add new data and one to update, but ideally, I'd like the button to either take you to the update or add a new page depending on data already being added to the database.

So is there a way to have a single button that automatically takes you to the correct view?

I imagine i'll need some kind of logic within the view to handle this. But im not sure what this would be?

Views.py

```
@login_required
def AddFundamentals(request,project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = AddFundamentalsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.project = project
            form.save()
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
    else:
        form = AddFundamentalsForm()
    return render(request, 'pages/add_fundamentals.html', {'project': project, "form": form})



@login_required
def UpdateFundamentals(request,project_id):
    project= Project.objects.get(pk=project_id)
    form = AddFundamentalsForm(request.POST or None, instance=project)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('dahsboard.html')
    return render(request, 'pages/update_fundamentals.html', {'project': project, "form": form})
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Add Evaluation Data <i class="mdi mdi-chevron-down"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'add_fundamentals' project.id %}">Add Critical Fundamentals <span class="badge bg-success"></span></a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'update_fundamentals' project.id %}">Update Critical Fundamentals</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Secondary Elements</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Other Elements</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Founders and Development Team</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Marketing Assessment</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Product Evaluation</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- end col -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Views.py

```
@login_required
def Add_or_updateFundamentals(request,project_id):
    project = Project.objects.filter(pk=project_id)
    check_exist = project.exists()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if check_exist:
            form = AddFundamentalsForm(request.POST,instance=project[0])
        else:
            form = AddFundamentalsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if not check_exist:
                 form.instance.project = project
            form.save()
            return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')
    else:
        if check_exist:
            form = AddFundamentalsForm(instance=project[0])
            return render(request, 'pages/update_fundamentals.html', {'project': project, "form": form})
        else:
            form = AddFundamentalsForm()
            return render(request, 'pages/add_fundamentals.html', {'project': project, "form": form})
```

Comment: Thanks Amadou. I think this is working, but do i need this to redirect to the `update_fundamentals.html` when the data exists.  Where would i add this in?

Comment: @JacksWastedLife now you do not need the two other views you can just use this one and you can use one of your form maybe this `update_fundamentals.html`

Comment: Ok, i get that, but the form when containing data needs to display what has already been added. so for example the website field would contain the previously added website.  i would normally use `{{ form.instance.project_website }}`  but this would mean i would have that logic in the form regardless of data being added before?

Comment: @JacksWastedLife i have make all that logic in the view 1) first i check whether the user already has a project or not 2) if he has one i show him the form as if we was updating it if he has not i go to 3.3) if he has not i show him the form and in the post request i inject `form.instance.project = project` 4) i save the form.in your template you just need this `{{ form }}`

Comment: Ok, I think I understand whats going on here. I actually need it to go to a different html template.  So if data exists go to `update_fundamentals` else go to `add_fundamentals`

Comment: @JacksWastedLife i updated my answer but note that even the first one will work.